# Delete specific user from keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am checking the Keycloak [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/4.8/rest-api/index.html#_map).

I am trying to figure out which endpoint should I use for deleting specific user from KeyCloak. I am using it within my Symfony project on REST Api..

Could someone clearfy that for me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you need to get an access token from a user with admin-alike permission, for instance:

```
curl    -d "client_id=admin-cli" \
        -d "username=$ADMIN_NAME" \
        -d "password=$ADMIN_PASSWORD" \
        -d "grant_type=password" \
        <YOUR_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN>/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

From that response (*i.e.,* a Keycloak Token Object), extract the access token. Then you need to use that access token, to call the following endpoints:

To delete a user you need to use the endpoint:

```
DELETE <YOUR_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/users/{USER_ID}
```

to get the `USER_ID` you can call the endpoint:

```
GET <YOUR_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN>/auth/admin/realms/<YOUR_REALM>/users/?username=<THE_USERNAME>
```

or you can copy and paste from the Keycloak Admin Console, under the tab users:

[image]